# remove power off soft button from power menu

Tags: android

I deeply apologize if this question has been asked before and been answered as I have been searching for weeks now but could not get an answer to my question/problem. I am simply looking for a way to disable the power menu that comes up after the power button is long pressed. I have tried to capture the longkeypress event but could not intercept the power menu. I am simply trying to achieve this so I can turn off the phone from the app I am developing not directly by the currently power off menu.

So guys if there is a direction or short codes to just disable the power menu or prevent the menu from coming up or remove the turn off and airplane mode soft buttons from the menus.

I can capture the normal press of power button and perform an operation however my aim at this point is to prevent the phone from switching off but be able to switch off from my app.

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: That is out of your hands. And furthermore, users have an expectation of the power button always letting them turn off their phone. What use case do you have where it wouldn't make someone angry that you took that away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, that's OS level functionality.  You'd need a custom ROM to do so.

Comment: I think you are right Gabe, will find another means of achieving my aim thank you.